# Running my local bash script on remote server

Tags: bash, ssh

How can I run my local bash script remotely with SSH access?

Could I change the folder before run the script?

Answer (score 6):

You can use this command to access your specific folder (e.g. html), then run your local bash script:

```
ssh user@remote_host 'cd html && bash ' < ../snippets/myCustomBash.sh
```

Comment: Checking `cd` for errors might possibly make more sense with `&&` instead of the assuming it worked with the `; `